# How to get boolean value from a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

what is the logic behind a checkbox value?
It is allways `on` regardless checked or not
I'm expecting a boolean like `on-off`, `0-1`, `true-false`...
How can I get this?

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
    let x = $('#inptest').val();
    console.log(x);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
<input type='checkbox' id='inptest'>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/how-do-i-check-whether-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-jquery